# Best way to do a belongs_to association with mulitples models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I would like to create an association with meta_tags model to 2 another models :

```
class MetaTag < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :post
  has_one :category
  has_one :sub_category
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meta_tag
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta_tag
end
```

in my posts_controller :

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.build_meta_tag
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to admin_path
    else
      flash.alert = @post.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
      render :new
    end
  end 

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(
      :id,
      :title,
      :body,
      :slug,
      :statut,
      :created_at,
      :updated_at,
      :user_id,
      :sub_category_id,
      :main_image,
      :meta_tag_id,
      meta_tag_attributes: [
        :meta_title
      ]
    )
  end
```

When I want to create a post and the associated meta_tags, the post is created but not the asociation

How can I do to create post & meta_tag in the same method ?

**UPDATE :**

meta_tag association don't exist before @post.save

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meta_tag, optional: true, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta_tag
end
```

posts_controller.rb :

```
 def new
    @post = Post.new
    @meta = @post.build_meta_tag

  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      @post.create_meta_tag(meta_params)
      redirect_to admin_path
    else
      flash.alert = @post.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
      render :new
    end
  end

  def meta_params
    params.require(:meta_tag).permit(
      :meta_title,
      :meta_description
    )
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(
      :id,
      :title,
      :body,
      :slug,
      :statut,
      :created_at,
      :updated_at,
      :user_id,
      :sub_category_id,
      :main_image,
      :meta_tag_id
    )
  end
```

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?  Your controller may not be handling Strong Parameters.  So you may need to define a method in the controller post_params where you do a params.require(:post).permit( ....)

Comment: I'm using rails 6.1.3 and added my strongs params in the question

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37151 will explain it better than anything else.

Comment: @engineersmnky I did something, but I think is tricky. I updated my question and now,  I can save post and post.meta_tag but if a validation is wrong, all meta_tag field are rended empt